# NEXT-AUTH callback redirect only in signin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, next.js, next-auth

I want to use redirect only when signIn().  I have tried several methods.

1. Use callback redirect in[...nextauth].tsx

This method make my app will redirect on both sign in and sign out.  Not for my situation.

```
 callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return "/account/loadingregister";
    },
  },
```

2. Inline use redirect in the component.  However, this only works for signOut callback, I need this work in sign in callback.

```
<button onClick={() => signIn({ callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/abc" })}>
     Sign In
</button>

<button onClick={() => signOut({ callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/foo" })}>
     Sign Out
</button>
```

3. Both are used.  The [...nextauth].tsx will be the first priority. And inline redirect will be ignored.

So, how can I redirect only in sign in function?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer. Need to use async function to redirect to other page after signIn.

```
const handleSignIn = async () => {
    await signIn("google", {
      callbackUrl: "/",
    });
  };

//component:

<button onClick={() => handleSignIn()}>Sign In</button>
```